Remote-SSH: Clicking 'Connect to Host' in VS Code Has No Response
Description:
I am experiencing an issue with Visual Studio Code (VS Code) where clicking the Connect to Host option under the SSH icon dropdown does not respond.
Steps I Have Tried:
Reinstalled VS Code.
Checked the disk for errors.
Reinstalled the Remote-SSH extension.
Error in Developer Tools:

ERR Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'after'): Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'after')
at f.h (c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:154:204747)

System Information:

Operating System: Windows 11 Home Edition, Version 22631.3880


VS Code Version: 1.91.1 (User Setup)

Additional Background Information:
Recently formatted a non-system disk, and the issue appeared after that.
Tried using VS Code Insider but encountered the same problem with SSH.
Any help or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
